# Showing disabled SectionItems expanded in SmartGWT

Tags: java, smartgwt

When you disable a DynamicForm in SmartGWT, all the items in the form become disabled and thus unresponsive. This is expected and correct behaviour.

The problem is that if there are collapsed [SectionItem](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/SectionItem.html)s in the form, they cannot be expanded before the form is re-enabled. Is there an easy way to make the sections interactive when a form is disabled?

Comment: Why you don't disabled selectively your items in the form?

Comment: That would violate the DRY principle, make the code messy and more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

SectionItem are FormItem whose drawing is handled by the containig DynamicForm.
Check http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=15008.

Following options exist in achieving the required behavior.
These options do not disable the entire canvas of the form.

**Option 1:**
Use following method in place of `form.setDisabled(true|false)` as `setFormDisabled(form, true|false);`.

```
private void setFormDisabled(DynamicForm form, boolean isDisabled) {
    FormItem[] fields = form.getFields();
    for (FormItem field : fields) {
        if (!(field instanceof SectionItem)) {
            field.setDisabled(isDisabled);
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**
Override `form.*Disabled()` methods and use as `form.setDisabled(true|false)`.

```
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm() {
    private boolean isDisabled;

    @Override
    public boolean getDisabled() {
        return isDisabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
        this.isDisabled = disabled;
        setFormDisabled(this, disabled);
    }
};
```

This can be enhanced with Generics if multiple types of items need to be kept enabled in different forms.